# Securing heavy-load shelves onto a sandy wall

Tags: walls, shelving, anchor

I have tried to install shelves with simple plastic wall anchors. These are Ikea wall shelves with one big metal bracket. The wall is apparently very sandy and I can feel the bracket pulling the anchors and bolts out even with a weak pull of my hand and these shelves are meant for a heavy load.

I can see [this post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/595/how-do-i-hang-shelves-on-poor-quality-brick-concrete-walls) on the subject and I have three questions:

- Why can't I simply use [metal sleeve bolts](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/595/how-do-i-hang-shelves-on-poor-quality-brick-concrete-walls) in concrete wall?
- Is there any practical way to find out what is the wall's material? I am not sure if it is blocks, concrete or something else.
- If it is not a concrete wall are the solutions in the link still valid?

Comment: Do you have photos? What is the locale of the construction? It's possible you have light plaster over some other substrate.

Comment: I will upload photos soon.

Comment: [Related](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/69128/installing-hook-on-strange-wall/69133#69133) - If that's what type of wall you have, toggle bolts should work relatively well. If anywhere you drill goes through sandy stuff for like ~2" and then pops through the wall, goes another inch or so and then stops dead (hitting brick), that's probably what it is. If it's an interior wall it won't stop dead, they'd be hollow.